# Wrestling with Python MySQLdb timedelta

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm converting a PHP program to Python. Apparently MySQLdb returns MySQL time fields as time deltas offset from midnight. So a database field containing a literal "08:00:00" (8:00 AM) is returned as 28,800 seconds. I have found some other posts confirming this behavior, but can't find code samples that help me get what I need.

I need to read a logged event's date and time, and determine how much time has passed:

```
event_date = mysql_result[0] # datetime object
event_time = mysql_result[1] # timedelta object

now = datetime.now()         # datetime object
elapsed_minutes = ???        # need integer
```

Iv'e read through the lengthy documentation for datetime on docs.python.org, but have been unsuccessful taking the datetime and timedelta values, comparing to the current time, and producing the number of elapsed minutes (or seconds) as an integer.

I'm not saying the answer isn't there or in another stack overflow post--just that I have been completely unsuccessful finding and implementing it myself. Can someone please lend a hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what `event_date` and `event_time` contain?

Comment: The mysql database fields might be "2012-10-22" and "13:19:00". This yields "datetime.date(2012, 10, 22)" for event_date and "datetime.timedelta(0, 49980)" for event_time. And now = "datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 22, 13, 55, 22, 911451)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [82]: import datetime as dt
In [85]: now = dt.datetime.now()

In [129]: event_date = dt.date(2012,10,22)    
In [155]: event_date = dt.datetime(event_date.year, event_date.month, event_date.day)

In [130]: event_time = dt.timedelta(seconds = 28800)    
In [131]: event = event_date + event_time  

In [132]: elapsed = now - event
Out[132]: datetime.timedelta(0, 35008, 781476)    
In [133]: elapsed.total_seconds()
Out[133]: 35008.781476    
In [134]: elapsed.total_seconds() // 60
Out[134]: 583.0
```

Or, in Python2.6, which does not have the `total_seconds` method:

```
In [149]: (elapsed.days*24*60*60+elapsed.seconds+elapsed.microseconds/1e6)//60
Out[149]: 583.0
```

Comment: I am developing under Python 2.6.5 and I think that time delta.total_seconds() was added in 2.7, is that right? [link](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

Comment: I notice in a comment that `event_date` is a `dt.date`, not a `dt.datetime`. In that case, we must convert `event_date` to a `dt.datetime` before adding `event_time`. Updating post...

Comment: Thanks for that. It works just fine when typed into an interactive session. When the same code is run under WSGI to serve a web page, it gives an error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'" The *elapsed* variable is created as a datetime.datetime interactively, but as a datetime.date on the web server. Can I force the "elapsed = now - event" to return a datetime.datetime object?

Comment: If `now - event` is raising `TypeError: ... 'datetime.datetime' and
'datetime.date'` then `event` must still be a `datetime.date`. Did you add `event_date = dt.datetime(event_date.year, event_date.month, event_date.day)` to force `event_date` to be a `datetime.datetime` object?

Comment: Interactive event result: datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 22, 8, 0) -- programatic event result: datetime.date(2012, 10, 22) -- both using the same code: event = event_date + event_time

Comment: All right. That extra conversion did the trick. Thanks a million for the quick and accurate response!